# How would one surgically alter an eye to have a verted retina?

Tags: anatomy, cyborg

The inverted retina is considered an [inefficient design](https://www.reddit.com/r/DebateEvolution/comments/kpqkm6/even_if_the_inverted_retina_is_good_design_as/) compared to the eyes in invertebrates.

How would one change this? Nanomachines? Genetics engineering? Vat grown eyes?

Comment: Actually the reference you give states the contrary: inverted retina is not an inefficient design.

Comment: What lead you to posting a self negating argument we wonder.

Comment: if you invert the eye, then wont you also have to invert how the brain processes sensory data to compensate for the now unflipped image? the eye will see correctly, sure, but the brain will see upside down.

Answer (score 1):

The human retina has blood vessels on top by a peculiarity of development and evolution.  Most of the blood vessels actually *are* underneath, in an outer layer called the choroid, but there are also some on top.  The ones on top are the result of the expansion of a small structure to provide gas and nutrient exchange to the vitreous humor from the blood until it ballooned to line the whole retina.   Birds have a smaller structure like that called the [pecten oculi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pecten_(avian_eye)) and the conus papillaris in reptiles is similar; the [falciform process](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1955633/) of fish is argued to have evolved independently, despite its similarity.

Conceivably, some change in development could revert the human eye to have the blood vessels concentrated in a process at the blind spot again.  However, relying on oxygen to diffuse that distance probably would be insufficient to power the robust neural circuitry of the retina.

Inverting *just* the neural layer would put the photoreceptors on top of that tissue at least.  But the current design relies on the retinal pigment epithelium to recycle worn-out photoreceptors from the tips of the photoreceptors ... and that is *pigmented*.  It lies just *under* the photoreceptors to stop stray light ... and if you have nerve cells under it, the stray light will go much further before being stopped at the choroid instead.  And the retinal pigment epithelium, now on top, would still contain pieces of shed photoreceptors, which are pigmented, even if it lost its own pigment.

Going back and redesigning the eye to that extent requires more or less the ability to re-evolve an eye from scratch.